InvalidAuthenticationToken "message":"Access token is empty"
while trying to authenticate my application to send an email with the help of microsoft azure with graph api, getting issue like how to resolve this
{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token is empty.","innerError":{"date":"2024-11-28T08:52:54","request-id":"b9cce320-a5f8-4aae-9278-53e9c14f9158","client-request-id":"b9cce320-a5f8-4aae-9278-53e9c14f9158"}}} 

I tried to get authorization, i am expecting to get authorization-code after redirecting to the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? client_id=your_client_id &response_type=code &redirect_uri=https://yourapp.com/redirect &scope=Mail.Send &response_mode=query &state=12345 with valid replaced values for client-id, redirect-uri, redirect-uri i am providing is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants

Please clarify what the actual issue is here. "i am expecting to get authorization-code" - and, did you? The error message you have quoted isn't about the code, but appears to be about an empty token in a subsequent API call.

Have you generated the access token with scope of Mail.Send?

I have generated the access token with the scope of scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],

@HemavathiGadi Could you share the screenshot of your API permission blade?

My API permission blade is email, Mail.Send, User.Read

@HemavathiGadi Have you pasted the generated access token while making POST request for sending mail?

@HemavathiGadi Any update on issue?

Initially, I got same error while requesting POST endpoint for sending mail.

To resolve the error, Ensure authorization: Bearer Token should not be empty and properly configured.
Registered Multi-Tenant Microsoft Entra ID application, Added Delegated type API permission of Mail.Send and Granted Admin consent:

Use below authorization endpoint at browser to get authorization_code :
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=<AppID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=YOUR REDIRECT URI
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send
&state=12345



Now, Generated Access token using below token endpoint with below parameters:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <APP_ID>
client_secret: <CLIENT SECRET>
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:AUTHORIZATION_CODE
client_secret:ClientSecret



After generating the access token, Use same token while making POST request for sending mail.
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail

{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "<EMAIL ADDRESS OF RECIPENT>"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "<CC's EMAIL ADDRESS>"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "false"
}

Authorization: Bearer Token
Body: application/json


References:
sendMail
How to solve invalid authentication token error

in my case grant admin consent for the organization i work for is not highlighted in API Permissions. My mail id is domain is not having @onmicrosoft.com at end

in vs code editor you are showing is with postman extension?
